# Notational inconsistency for subsets and strict subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I am reading "Introduction to Topology" by Gamelin and Greene (2nd edition) and I am confused by what appears to be an inconsistency in notation for subsets and strict subsets.

The image below shows page 61 from this book. From the solid red highlighted expressions, it appears that $A \subset B$ means $A$ is a subset (not strict) of $B$. However, from the blue dashed highlighted expression, it appears that $A \subseteq B$ means $A$ is a subset (not strict) of $B$.

Is this a typo in the book, or have I misunderstood something?

Frustratingly, they don't define the symbols $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ anywhere.

UPDATE: Thanks to the helpful comments and answer, it's clear that there is a notational inconsistency and the authors mean "subset" (not "strict subset") with both $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ on pg 61.

But, is it safe to assume they always mean "subset" (and never have a use for "strict subset") through the entire book? I'm new to topology, and there are other places where I cannot figure out whether they mean "strict subset". Is it likely that the entire book would never have a use for "strict subset"?

[image]

Comment: Many authors use $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ interchangeably, and use $\subsetneq$ for proper inclusion.  It would appear that is the case here, as the interior of  $A$ need not be a proper subset of $A$.

Comment: If $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ are equivalent, why would the authors switch back and forth between the two symbols? That would just add needless confusion.

Comment: The issue is there are three symbols. The ones that are unambiguous are $\subseteq$ and $\subsetneq$. Then some authors use $\subset$ as a synonym for whichever one they think is the more "basic". As to why *these* authors appear to be doing that, you'll have to ask them.

Comment: Hmm, I'll look to see if I can find the symbol $\subsetneq$ in the book. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've gone back through many pages of the book and do not see any use of $\subsetneq$, but the authors continue to use both $\subset$ and $\subseteq$. It is very hard for me to believe that the authors are arbitrarily switching between equivalent notations throughout the book. It seems much more likely that there is a typo.

Comment: Sloppy notation. Accept that not every book is perfect and get on with it. Besides: if you really get to the point of understanding their math that minor notational issues will appear in a different light.

Comment: It looks like an inconsistency in notation to me. In the case of "Evidently $\text{int}(S) \subset S$", the author is definitely using $\subset$ to mean "proper subset or equal to", and thus the author should be using $\subsetneq$ (or something similar) to mean "proper subset" (apparently not yet confirmed) and the author (probably) should NOT be using the symbol $\subseteq$ (which is done later). And it's not just one possible typo. In what you've quoted, $\subset$ is used in several places to mean "proper subset or equal to", and $\subseteq$ is used twice. **(continued)**

Comment: This is probably an editing oversight in which one of the authors (at least sometimes) used a different convention from the other author (or possibly a different convention was accidentally used during some of the 2nd edition edits/changes -- my guess is this, with $\subseteq$ being accidentally included) and not all of the inconsistencies were found during editing/proofing. I notice the same issue occurs elsewhere -- on p. 3 in the case of "proper subset or equal to", $\subseteq$ is used twice and $\subset$ is used once. **(continued)**

Comment: Interestingly, there are no subset symbols in the *List of Notations* on pp. 193-194, although the less ambiguous/author-specific notion for union and intersection do appear there. Even by 1983, when the first edition of the book was published, the old-style $+, \; \sum$ for union and $\cdot, \; \prod$ for intersection were very much sufficiently out-of-style, and authors then did not have to worry that readers were not familiar with the $\cup$ and $\cap$ notation (although often for completeness, $\cup$ and $\cap$ still tended to be in the symbol list of many books). **(continued)**

Comment: I also note in Gamelin/Greene that "subset" is not in the index, and as far as I can tell, "subset" is not defined (or a symbol for it defined) anywhere near the beginning of the text.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for taking a look through the text, that makes sense that the two authors might have been using different notations. This is frustrating because there are places in the text where I can't figure out whether they mean "subset" or "proper subset". Is it possible that they always mean "subset" and never used "proper subset" anywhere in the book?

Comment: *Is it possible that they always mean "subset" and never used "proper subset" anywhere in the book?* --- This doesn't excuse or explain the notation discrepancy you mention, but I think it is quite likely, since it's relatively rare in many traditional pure math areas to have to use the "proper subset" notion. Indeed, definitions are typically made so that the "inclusive subset notion" applies. (I'm wording this in analogy with OR in math having the "inclusive or" meaning.) So my earlier "apparently not yet confirmed" is probably more along the lines of "probably doesn't appear".

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you, that helps a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\subset$ and $\subseteq$ have the same meaning. Most authors prefer $\subset$ , but there are also authors using  $\subseteq$ . It is just a matter of taste. However, I agree to you that one should not use both symbols in the same text.

Having a quick view into the book, I only found very few occurrences of $\subseteq$ . I would therefore regard these as "unintended" occurrences. Perhaps the authors (there are two of them!) had different preferences, or made typos in the manuscript, or  $\subseteq$ was used erroneously in the print set created by  the book publisher - but that is pure speculation.

Your example $\operatorname{int} S \subset S$ from p. 61 contrasts to $\operatorname{int} Y \subseteq Y$ on p. 3. This should say enough: The use is not standardized in the book.

Comment: Some people use $\subset$ to mean proper subset, so they don't always have the same meaning

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think every instance of $\subset$ and $\subseteq$ in the book means "subset" (aka "proper subset or equal")? Or do you think that sometimes they mean "proper subset" and other times they mean "subset"? If it's the latter, I think I need to get a different topology book, because there are instances where I cannot figure out whether or not they mean "proper subset".

Comment: @C.M.O.B. All examples of $\subset$ that I found mean "subset" (which allows $=$).